# Splitting string into groups with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regular expression that allows me to split the following string in c#:

> $1.89 BROWN RICE ‐ 16 03/01 ‐ 03/07 1.29

into something like this:

- Group 1: BROWN RICE - 16
- Group 2: 03/01 ‐ 03/07
- Group 3: 1.29

Is it possible to achieve this with Regex?

Comment: Yes, probably. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the logic for the splitting? (and what happened to $1.89?) Say, (Price Title - quantity(?)) (date - date) (price) ?

Comment: Looks like (original price) (Title) - (Quantity) (Date Range of sale price) (Sale price) to me.  John, is that accurate?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The logic will be: Product - Qty, Date range, New Price. The Original price ($1.89) will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you Eric H. That is the correct logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think a regex will be better than splitting.

If it's original price (Product - Qty) (date range) (sale price), you can try something like

```
\$?\d+\.\d{2} ([A-Za-z ]+- *\d+) +(\d{2}/\d{2} *- *\d{2}/\d{2}) +\$?(\d+\.\d{2})
```

Title & Quantity are in captured group 1, date range in group 2, new price in group 3.

Explanation:

- `\$?\d+\.\d{2}`: a price, optional dollar sign, exactly two decimal places (for the cents). If you want to allow '$1' (ie no decimal places) then modify accordingly.
- `([A-Za-z ]+- *\d+)` Object name and quantity (separated by a hyphen). You may wish to modify this regex depending on the expected names you will get in (perhaps they aren't just consisting of letters and spaces).
- `(\d{2}/\d{2} *- *\d{2}/\d{2})` date range. I have no idea if yours is month/day or day/month, but depending on that you can make your regex a lot more exclusive if you wish (for example, a numeric date is `([012]\d|3[01])` and a month only goes from 1 to 12).
- `\$?(\d+\.\d{2})` the saleprice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried having a go with something like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)? Makes it easy to test out how to filter the data you're interested in. There's a bunch of hints in the top right which basically describes how to write regular expressions too...

First we want to capture the price but we dont' care about it so the `?` ignores that group:

```
(?:\$\d+\.\d+)
```

Since we know what the third part should look like, our first section of interest can gobble up anything in the middle:

```
(.*)
```

Next we want to match that date range:

```
(\d{2}/\d{2} ‐ \d{2}/\d{2})
```

And finally we want a floating point number:

```
(\d+\.\d+)
```

So in conclusion, something like this should work:

```
(?:\$\d+\.\d+) (.*) (\d{2}/\d{2} ‐ \d{2}/\d{2}) (\d+\.\d+)
```

You'll need to escape the backslashes to include that in c#

Answer (score 0):

```
(\$\d\.\d{2}) (.*?) (\d{2}/\d{2} - \d{2}/\d{2}) (.*)
```

This works on your example. It may need to be improved if you have any more data variations

```
(\$\d\.\d{2}) - Match the price $0.00 
   - If prices can be more than $9 then you'd need to 
     make this match one or more (\$\d+\.\d{2})
(.*?) - Lazy match everything till the next group
(\d{2}/\d{2} - \d{2}/\d{2}) - Match the date range
(.*) - Match what ever is left
```

You may also wish to put start and end line constraints if you're reading a bunch of these from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\$\d*\.\d{2,}\s([^-]+\s[-]\s\d+)\s(\d{2}\/\d{2}\s[-]\s\d{2}\/\d{2})\s(\d*\.\d{2,})$/
```

Group 1 : Brown Rice - 16
Group 2 : 03/01 ‐ 03/07
Group 3 : 1.29 (will also match 0.29 and .29)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    (\$\d+\.\d+)\s(.*?)\s(\d{2}/\d{2}\s-\s\d{2}/\d{2})\s(\d+\.\d+)
```

---

`(\$\d+\.\d+)`   matches the price in dollars

`(.*?)`                 matches the product name

`(\d{2}/\d{2}\s-\s\d{2}/\d{2})`  matches the date range

`(\d+\.\d+)`       matches the second price

---

I noted that the minus sign (`-`) in your example uses a different character code as the standard minus sign. Therefore, my Regex did not want to work until I replaced your "-" by normal ones.